# Does anyone know how to work this out?

Tags: java

What output is produced by the following program? 
The answer says 7 but i have trouble working it out.

```
public class practice {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int i = 5;
        int b = g(i);
        System.out.println(b+i);

    }

    public static int f(int i) {
        int n = 0;
        while (n * n <= i) {n++;}
        return n-1;
    }

    public static int g(int a) {
        int b = 0;
        int j = f(a);
        b = b + j;
        return b;
    }


}
```

Comment: Try working it out on paper line by line.

Comment: i did but i am getting lost somehow and i get wrong numbers

Comment: Well, you should show us your work. (You're probably getting downvotes because you didn't.)

Answer (score 2):

I assume main is getting called. Here is a list of steps that happen

1. `g` gets called with `5` as its parameter.
2. then in function `g`, `f` gets called with `g`'s parameter, which is `5`
3. In function `f` `n` is set to zero, a while loop is called and every time `n*n` is less than or equal to its parameter, which is 5, n is incremented. below outlines the while loop.

   1. 0*0 is less than 5, increment `n` from 0 to 1 and continue.
   2. 1*1 is less than 5, increment `n` from 1 to 2 and continue.
   3. 2*2 is less than 5, increment `n` from 2 to 3 and continue.
   4. 3*3 is **not** less than 5, break out of the loop.
4. `n-1`, which is 3-1=2, gets returned back to where it was called, in variable `j` in function `g`.
5. `b` gets assigned to `b+j` which is `0+2`.
6. `b` gets returned back to variable `b` in function `main`.
7. `b+i`, which is `5+2`, which is **7**, gets printed as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Your using a number (5) and basically checking what is the first whole number squared that equals more than than 5. Then you negate 1 from the answer and add 5.**

**So here is the maths:**

***1. Find the first whole number squared that is larger than 5***

- 0*0 = 0 //+1
- 1*1 = 1 //+1
- 2*2 = 4 //+1
- 3*3 = 9 //3*3 is the first value over 5; loop breaks

***2. Negate 1 from 3 (the first whole number when squared that is larger than***

- 3 - 1 = 2; //using 3, negate 1 (also could have used n--)

***3. Using the final value 2 add 5***

- 2 + 5 = 7 //using 2 add 5

**Answer is 7.**

***There is some really unnecessary stuff in this code, such as the two extra methods.***